# Set up login and password inputs in HTML

Tags: html, authentication, login-control

What is the correct way to set up login and password input boxes in HTML?

The reason I ask is because the program I use to manage all of my passwords (1Password) is not picking up that I have just entered credentials that it should attempt to save. This makes me think that I have set up the form wrong.

The credentials are being sent via Ajax over an SSL connection after the `click()` event on the submit button. They are stored in the post body as a JSON object. Not sure of they need to be in the headers or something?

This is what I have on the page so far:

```
Username: <input id='username_input' type='text'><br>
Password: <input id='password_input' type='password'><br>
<input id='login-button' type='submit' value='login'>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inputs don't have any names, so no data will be sent to the server when the form is submitted. Try:

```
Username: <input id='username_input' name='username' type='text'><br>
Password: <input id='password_input' name='password' type='password'><br>
<input id='login-button' type='submit' value='login'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use double quotation marks for the attributes:

```
Username: <input id="username_input" type="text" /><br />
Password: <input id="password_input" type="password" /><br />
<input id="login-button" type="submit" value="login" />
```

Additionally, wrapping the fields in a form element may work.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing functional in HTML which is changed by using double rather single quotes, except the way you need to encode any single and double quotes inside them